# Override $templateCache to be case insensitive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-templatecache, angularjs-decorator

Can one override core provider like `$templateCache` while maintaining reference to the original provider ?
I'd like to override `$templateCache` to be case insensitive.

I.E. something like

```
var normalGet = $templateCache.get;
var normalPut = $templateCache.put;
$templateCache.get = function(key) { normalGet(key.toLowerCase()); };
$templateCache.put = function(key,value) { normalPut(key.toLowerCase(), value); };
```

But less hacky, more DI-style ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say use `decorator` to modify the actual `Provider` code which will be done at configuration phase before coming into action.

We used `$templateCacheProvider` because `Provider` appended prefix indicate that its `provider`(it can be `Directive` when you are modifying directive DDO of directive). You have to place this code inside `config` phase of your application.

**Code**

```
app.config(['$provide', Decorate]);
function Decorate($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('$templateCacheProvider', 
    ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
      var templateCache = $delegate[0];

      var normalGet = templateCache.get;
      var normalPut = templateCache.put;
      templateCache.get = function(key) { return normalGet(key.toLowerCase()); };
      templateCache.put = function(key,value) { normalPut(key.toLowerCase(), value); };

      return $delegate;
    }]);
}
```

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar my bad, corrected, Thanks for heads up. well, may I know what you specifically don't understand?

Comment: I was not sure how/where/to fire that - so the $provide was what I was after :).

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar checkout updated answer. and let me know if you still unclear with whats happening.

Comment: I had to replace `$delegate[0]` with `$delegate` to make it work.

Comment: I had to replace `$provide.decorator('$templateCacheProvider',`   with `$provide.decorator('$templateCache,`. And also use niaher's fix. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, worked perfectly for me.

```js
angular.module('utils').config(['$provide', ($provide) => {
    $provide.decorator('$templateCache',
        ['$delegate', ($delegate: ITemplateCacheService) => {
            let templateCache = $delegate;
            let caseSenstiveGet = templateCache.get;
            let caseSenstivePut = templateCache.put;
            templateCache.get = (key) => { return caseSenstiveGet(key.toLowerCase()); };
            templateCache.put = (key, value) => { return caseSenstivePut(key.toLowerCase(), value); };
            return $delegate;
        }]);
}]);
```